# Using Google Translate in a Excel VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

Folks....For some years now I have used the following function in one of my Excel macros to help me compose photo captions from English into French.  This AM it started throwing an error, which pointed to the `.Send` command in the code below:

```
Public Function getGoogleTranslation(strSource As String, strSourceLang As String, strDestLang As String) As String
Dim strURL As String, x As String

strURL = "http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=t&text=" & _
         Replace(strSource, " ", "%20") & _
         "&hl=en&sl=" & strSourceLang & _
         "&tl=" & strDestLang & "&multires=1&pc=0&rom=1&sc=1"

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "get", strURL, False
    .send
    x = .responseText
End With

getGoogleTranslation = Replace(Replace(Split(x, ",")(0), "[", ""), """", "")

End Function
```

When I copy/paste the contents of strURL directly into IE, the first time I got a CAPTCHA and a comment that they are checking for 'robots'. The second time it worked directly.  They must be setting a cookie??

Is there anyway around this? Or another way to get simple phrases translated in a macro?

Thanks....RDK

Comment: You will need to use Google translate API for browsers. You'll be given a a connection token. This will help you avoid the annoying captchas. Try this as well: http://web.archive.org/web/20110720142541/http://basharkokash.com/post/2010/04/19/Bing-Translator-for-developers.aspx

Comment: I assume you are referring to the  Google Translator Toolkit?  I browsed that quickly and it appeared to be geared toward web page code and not VBA.  Am I wrong?

I also followed the link you provided and other related links.  WOW, using Bing Translator is a WHOLE lot more complicated than what I posted above.

Comment: OK, done with Google Translate!  It is no longer free for VBA usage even as small as mine.  Looking into using Microsoft Translator via VBA.  Just signed up on Microsoft Azure Marketplace and 2 million character/month for free.

Comment: Happy for you, can please post that as an answer so that other people can benefit in the future?

Comment: JLILI....Issue fixed with new code using Microsoft Translate.  I'll report back on how well MS Translate compares to my previous experiences with Google Translate....

Comment: JLILI....OK, after signing up at https://datamarket.azure.com to create an account, then click on the "Application" link and create an "application".  You will be provided with a client id and a secret password for the application. Finally, for VBA code, go to https://sysmod.wordpress.com/2012/01/09/microsoft-translator-vba-code-sample/.  I had to modify the code a bit as I'm using Excel 2003, but basically it is ready to  use after you include your ID and Password....RDK

Answer (score 2):

OK, done with Google Translate! It is no longer free for VBA usage even as small as mine. Now using Microsoft Translator via VBA. Just signed up on Microsoft Azure Marketplace and get 2 million character/month for free.

I've been using this system for several months now and it works as good as Google Translate did.  Not perfect, but good enough....RDK

Answer (score 0):

The following is just beta-realisation of a google-translation module for vba:
(used it for fast translation of a software)... 
maybe you need manually check the text afterwards for correctness.

```
Private Function GoogleTranslate(ByVal Text4Translation, ByVal resLang, ByVal srcLang) As String
Dim IEApp As Object
Dim IEDoc As Object
Dim IEUrl As String
Dim IESrc As String
Dim IEBeg As Long
Dim IEEnd As Long
' Neues Browser Objekt erzeugen
Set IEApp = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' Browser versteckt ausführen (höhere Geschwindigkeit)
'IEApp.Visible = False
' URL Generieren
Text4Translation = Replace(Text4Translation, " ", "%20")
IEUrl = "https://translate.google.com/#" & srcLang & "/" & resLang & "/" & Text4Translation
' HTML-Datei aufrufen
IEApp.navigate IEUrl
Do
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
Loop Until IEApp.busy = False
Set IEDoc = IEApp.document
' Quelltext einlesen
IESrc = IEDoc.body.innerHTML
' Bereich auslesen
IEBeg = InStr(1, IESrc, "result_box")
If IEBeg = 0 Then
    IESrc = " # Nothing found"
Else
    IEEnd = InStr(IEBeg, IESrc, "</div")
    IESrc = Mid(IESrc, IEBeg + 40, IEEnd - IEBeg - 40)
    IESrc = Replace(IESrc, "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "hps" & Chr(34) & ">", "")
    IESrc = Replace(IESrc, "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "atn" & Chr(34) & ">", "")
    IESrc = Replace(IESrc, "<span class=" & Chr(34) & "hps atn" & Chr(34) & ">", "")
    IESrc = Replace(IESrc, "<span>", "")
    IESrc = Replace(IESrc, "</span>", "")
    If IESrc = "" Then IESrc = " # Instr-Error"
End If
Set IEApp = Nothing
GoogleTranslate = IESrc
End Function
```

resLang = "de","en", ... (TargetLanguage)

srcLang = "de","en", ... (SourceLanguage)

(Attention, its just a workaround!)

Comment: Is the Google service now free for low volume usage?  When I bailed out on Google they wanted REAL money for my few Mb of usage

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to get **Phonetic** of Google transcript (As string)
(It's just below TextBox, when translate from English using one word)

Comment: This answer could be a comment, or you can try to detail it more.

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to query Google Translate directly via a short VBA macro. It works by first resting the cursor on a cell containing the phrase you'd like translated.

You then run the macro and in a cell you've reserved for this it creates a Google Translate search string URL and the macro code then opens your default browser and follows that Website hyperlink.

The hyperlink is: "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate " followed by the search phrase

I've tried it in Firefox with Chinese, Russian, Ukrainian and German phrases so far, using the original accented characters pasted as HTML into Excel cells.

Google Translate correctly identifies the language and outputs in my preferred language, English, perfectly every time.

Here's my macro code:

```
Sub TranslateSelection()

#Before running, select cell with text to be translated

#Change cell that will contain the hyperlink as needed. 

range("b2").value = "=" & ActiveCell.Address
    
range("b2").value = "https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate " & range("b2").value

ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=range("b2").value

End Sub
```

You can also make a hyperlink within your worksheet by entering a formula to get the translation with one click via this string:

=HYPERLINK("https://www.google.com/search?q=google+translate "&C14)

In this case, the cell containing the string we'd like the translation for is C14.

If you copy that formula down a column of cells next to the column of cells you'd like translations for it should create directly working hyperlinks for all.

However, at least in the Excel 2003 program I originally wrote this for, Excel sometimes doesn't refresh the hyperlink string contents with the new information, although its text may appear to correctly change when you change its translation input.

To get around this, create a hyperlink to the hyperlinked cell.

While the root hyperlink created by my method may not actually update (the link to the previous entry may remain in Excel's memory), the link to it always will refresh the new info.

For example, if you created the hyperlink in cell D15, you might put this into cell E15:

=Hyperlink(D15)

I suspect newer versions of Excel don't have the flaw that requires the above work-around to ensure that hyperlinks with  concantonated strings dynamically update.

Comment: I can see that this answer relates to the topic of the question (i.e. translation) but I'm not clear how it answers the original question ... how should a user use your code to obtain translated text within their VBA codebase (as it appears this answer just opens a web page)?

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for your comment. The original question was from someone who used Excel VBA to open a Google Web query page but couldn't then press the enter key to finally DO the search. My code pre-fills the Google query page AND runs it with the search term entered via VBA. That gets over the original questioner's final hurdle. I don't know how to actually grab the result and put it back into the Excel sheet. I simply copy and paste the translated result back into Excel. If you have VBA code that will do that extraction back into Excel automatically, please post it. Thanks.