# how to substitute cell letters depending in data set excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Here is an example of what I need:

[image]

Comment: there are `SUBSTITUTE` and `REPLACE` functions in excel.

Comment: ok, but i want replace or substitute according data in table that contain letters and corespondent letter

Comment: You've shown no original effort. It isn't even clear what is a right-to-left reading order and what is a left-to-right reading order. Show what you've come up with and **ask a specific question** regarding that effort.

Comment: Why trying to reinvent the wheel? look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532088/using-google-translate-in-a-excel-vba-macro

Comment: Actually, you don't need VBA, take a look [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHAI5.gif).