# Macro code to translate excel file to Japanese language

Tags: excel

I am trying to work on a file and needs to translate the file to Japanese. Can someone help me how to work on a macro code. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532088/using-google-translate-in-a-excel-vba-macro? What have you tried so far and what problem do you have?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Translate text using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098260/translate-text-using-vba)